# Pentaho PDI 9 (Kettle): Kitchen can't continue because the job couldn't be loaded

Tags: pentaho, kettle, pdi

I'm not using any repository, I'm trying to run a local job but it doesn't run and even setting log level to debug it doesn't really writes anything useful. I'm calling Kitchen like this (Ubuntu):

`sh kitchen.sh -job:"/home/myuser/jobs/job.kjb"`

Also tried

`sh kitchen.sh -job:"job.kjb" -dir:"/home/myuser/jobs/"`

And also tried using "=" instead of ":".

I've seen some people had problems because of the repositories file, but as I said I'm not using any. "repositories.xml" didn't exist tho, so I created it empty on "/home/myuser/.kettle" and "/home/myuser/pdi/data-integration/.kettle" and asked the script to look for some fake repository and it indeed looks for any repos in both files, which it doesn't do if I don't ask it for use any repo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that "dir" only works for pointing at local repository files, not a local directory containing job files. There's another parameter to set the job file route: "file".

`sh kitchen.sh -file="/home/myuser/jobs/job.kjb"`